# List of threads of a specific application on tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, memory-leaks

So, the scenario is that I have multiple application in a single tomcat, and once in a while I have to update them without restarting the service.

To prevent some leaks (presumably generated by classes that I don't have access to [i.e., TimerThread that never ends]) when I reload or redeploy applications on tomcat 7, I decided to list the threads when destroying the context and stop/interrupt them by force.
I know that it doesn't sound like a perfect approach, but it seems the one that's working, for I couldn't find a point I could close the thread nicely. Therefore, I'm stuck with them generating these leaks.

I listed them with "Thread.getAllStackTraces()", but it gives me all the threads in the JVM apparently, and I just wanted the threads of a specific application, so I'd be able to iterate over them and find the one(s) I must interrupt.
I used "getName()" to find them.

Well, if anyone can clarify me on this...

Java 7
Tomcat 7

Comment: can use kill -3 processId in the terminal, will dump the thread stack trace in the log file.

Comment: actually I need to find them inside the Java code. So I can interrupt them when the application is shutting down.

Comment: I know this is not the question you're asking, but if I were you, I would rather run a dedicated Tomcat instance for each webapp. Tomcat is so lightweight, it wouldn't incur any performance problem, and you could then kill or redeploy any webapp at will without impacting the others. Also, it would allow you to fine-tune the JVM memory settings per application rather than globally.

Comment: Yes... I thought about that, and it came up as an alternative, but I'm talking about 40+ applications, which makes it not that simple. I figured so far that it'd be less complicated to have one application sever for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I want to thank the guys that commented on my doubt above.

Anyway... I kept looking for an answer and couldn't list the threads as I thought it'd be the best way so solve the problem. Then, I decided to look over somewhere else, over the libraries and found that one of them, apache.commons.dbcp version 1.4 was destined to Java 6, and as I was using Java 7, it misteriously creates a TimerThread that never ends, therefore creating a leak. Updating to apache.commons.dbcp2 for Java 7+ made the Application never even start this TimerThread I mentioned.
It looks good now.